# Insert chat into ConversationBufferMemory

Tags: python, mongodb, openai-api, langchain

I have a mongoDB that stores user chat history using their session ID.

I need to pass this history to ConversationRetrievalChain, using the ConversationBufferMemory.

How can I transform/ insert the history into a new ConversationBufferMemory?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to

1. Create `MessagesPlaceholder` in `PromptTemplate`

```py
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", "You are a helpful chatbot"),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
        ("human", "{input}"),
    ]
)
```

2. Generate a memory. In your case, you can extract the `memory` from your MongoDB

```py
chain = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(
        history=RunnableLambda(memory.load_memory_variables) | itemgetter("history")
    )
    | prompt
    | model
)

inputs = {"input": "hi im bob"}
response = chain.invoke(inputs)
print(response)
```

3. Save the output context into `memory`

```py
memory.save_context(inputs, {"output": response.content})
print(memory.load_memory_variables({})

inputs = {"input": "whats my name"}
response = chain.invoke(inputs)
print(response)
```

The reference doc > https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/cookbook/memory